# How can I start program on boot in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, cron, root, startup

Is the root crontab the only way?  I'm starting up a MC server and don't want it to need me to manually restart it each time the server reboots for whatever reason.  I don't want any login required for these programs to initialise.

I'm using `ssh` to get into this server, it's a VPS, nothing local.

Answer (score 6):

There are more than one way to accomplish this.

1. You can put your startup script in `/etc/init.d` and make it resemble to one of the existing scripts over there. But depending on your Linux comfort level, this may be a little daunting.
2. You can make this a service and make the service start at the boot time. Just do a google search on "*how to make my program a service*" and you will come across a lot of pages. More than what you can shake a stick at.
3. If your app is startin g with one single command and is not dependent on anything else, you can add the start-up command at the end of `/etc/rc.local` file.

You can also put it in the cron to execute at the startup but this is not the way  it should be done, in my *opinion*

Comment: Thanks!  The original advice I was given from a web page was to run the following...

    @reboot cd ~/McMyAdmin && screen -dmS McMyAdmin ./MCMA2_Linux_x86_64

...sadly it didn't work using my non-root account.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu normally has Vixie cron installed. You can use @reboot for a normal user's `crontab` file. From the man page:

```
Instead of the first five fields, one  of  eight  special  strings  may
appear:

          string         meaning
          ------         -------
          @reboot        Run once, at startup.
          ....
```

Comment: The advice I was given was to add this to the crontab...

    @reboot cd ~/McMyAdmin && screen -dmS McMyAdmin ./MCMA2_Linux_x86_64

...but sadly it didn't work. :(

Comment: You should at least expand the paths (not use `~`). Or better make a script in which you do everything, assuming your PATH is only `/usr/bin:/bin` and then call that script from the crontab.